# PHP passing a class name becomes a string when passed to a function

Tags: php

Here's what I want to do:

```
public function all($model) {
  $query = 'SELECT ' . implode(', ', $model::$fields) ....;
}
```

Called like this:

```
$thing->all(Account);
```

I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in /home/mark/public_html/*/account.php on line 15
```

When inspecting `$model` with `var_dump` it turns out its a string. In the the first example if I change `$model` to `Account` on the $query line it works fine.

How can a take a string and turn it back into a class?

Edit: Updated example and title to reflect the problem isn't with `self`.

Solution: Since I'm not using PHP5.3, I had to resort to using eval() to get what I wanted. Thanks everybody!

Comment: What version of php are you using?  I think you are required to use php 5.3 to use a variable for the class name to access a static variable within that class.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Classes are not first-class citizens in PHP, as such they may not be stored in variables, passed as function arguments, or returned from functions.

However, PHP will let you simulate a first-class citizen by using a string containing the name of the class, in certain situations:

```
$class = "Account";

$instance = new $class(); // You can create instances

call_user_func(array($class, 'frobnicate')); // You can call static functions
```

That's about all in PHP < 5.3. However, with [PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), you can also:

```
$class::frobnicate(); // cleanly call static functions

$fields = $class::$fields; // access static variables
```

Comment: "frobnicate" is my new favorite word.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to access a static variable, so it looks like I'll need PHP 5.3. Thanks.

Comment: I shouldn't be giving this advice, since `eval` is evil... but you can with appropriate precautions use `eval('return '.$class.'::$fields;')` to get that static variable. Or use a static function instead. :)

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. Agreed on the evilness, though ;)

Comment: Since PHP 5.5 you can also use the "class" static member to access the fully qualified name, for example `Account::class`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class

Answer (score 1):

I have also experienced receiving such Fatal Error: `Class 'MyClass' not found` when you're class has a specific namespace, then it's probably the namespacing. You need to also mention the namespace in your String variable.

```
$class = "App\MyClass"; // mention the namespace too
$instance = new $class();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `self` this way : it can only be used in a static context (i.e. inside a static method) to point to the class -- and not its name.

If you are working with non-static methods (seems you are), you should use `$this`, instead of `self`.

Actually, before PHP 5.3, you cannot use a static method/data with a "dynamic" (i.e contained in a variable) class name -- see the examples on the page [Static Keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) : they only work with PHP 5.3, for that kind of manipulation.

Which means a portion of code like this one :

```
class ClassA {
    public static $data = 'glop';
}

$className = 'ClassA';
var_dump($className::$data);
```

Will not work with PHP < 5.3

Comment: I'm actually using inside of of a static class function, but it doesn't work if I pass the class name either.

Comment: @Mark : yes ; it's because you cannot do something like `$className::$data` with PHP < 5.3 ;; it's only possible with PHP >= 5.3

Answer (score 0):

See Wikipedia on the [scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator). Especially see the section on PHP and Hebrew.

Comment: I get what T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM. The wiki article doesn't explain why I can't do the above.

Answer (score -1):

I find this similar line works in my Laravel app:

```
$thing->all(new Account);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try '$this' instead of self.

Self does work this way in PHP. PHP thinks it encounters an unknown constant, which it can't find, and then it assumes it's a string containing 'self'.

Edit: Can you post the class and the code where you instantiate the object?

Comment: I don't think that's it - it doesn't work if I pass the class name either.

Comment: self does exist in php.  self refers to the current objects class type for use in static context.